# PHP | Not sure if this looping algorithm is the most efficient

Tags: php, performance, loops, logic

I have a small program that I've built for fun, but I am not sure that the nested loop is the most efficient way to get my end result.

I have the following data:

```
  Name         qty       sub
Widget_1   |   100   |   5   
Widget_2   |   500   |   10
Widget_3   |   1000  |   15
```

What am I **intending**

Take `qty` and divide by `sub` to get `term`.  So I create another key in the array:

```
$widget_1['term] = $widget_1['qty'] / $widget_1['sub'];
```

Now I have

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Widget 1
            [qty] => 100
            [sub] => 5
            [term] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Widget 2
            [qty] => 500
            [sub] => 10
            [term] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Widget 3
            [qty] => 1000
            [sub] => 15
            [term] => 67 //Rounded from 66.6
        )

)
```

I am looping through, and at the end of each individual `term`, add the `sub` to the following `widget`.

So for example, at the end of `$widget[0]`'s term, there will still be a `term` of `30` left for `$widget[1]` and a `qty` of `300`

At that point, I take `$widget[0]`'s `sub` and add it to `$widget[1]`'s `sub`,effectively decreasing the remaining `term` for `widget[1]`.

Then `$widget[1]`'s *updated* term becomes `20` -- effectively reducing `$widget[1]`'s **actual** term to 40.

Then at the end of `$widget[1]`'s `term` of 40 --  Take the aggregated `$widget[1]`'s `sub` and add it to `$widget[2]`.s sub.

A term of 40 has passed for `$widget[2]` at a sub of 15.  Making `$widget[2]'s` remainder `qty` 400.  I take `$widget[1]`'s aggregated `sub` of 15, and add it to `$widget[2]`'s original `sub` to make 30.  The *updated* `term` for `$widget[2]` now becomes 13.  Making `$widget[2]`'s **actual** total `term` 54 instead of 67

Here is my program -- Run it command line, it does functions as expected -- I am just curious if this is the best practice, or if there is a more efficient use of `functions` / `loops`?  Maybe it's just me, but this feels "messy".  Checking for the `qty` to be greater than `sub` and less than 0 etc etc.  Is there a better algorithm to attain the same results in a cleaner, more efficient format?

```
<?php

$widgets = array();

$widgets[0]['name'] = 'Widget 1';
$widgets[0]['qty'] = 100;
$widgets[0]['sub'] = 5;
$widgets[0]['term'] = $widgets[0]['qty'] / $widgets[0]['sub'];

$widgets[1]['name'] = 'Widget 2';
$widgets[1]['qty'] = 500;
$widgets[1]['sub'] = 10;
$widgets[1]['term'] = $widgets[1]['qty'] / $widgets[1]['sub'];

$widgets[2]['name'] = 'Widget 3';
$widgets[2]['qty'] = 1000;
$widgets[2]['sub'] = 15;
$widgets[2]['term'] = $widgets[2]['qty'] / $widgets[2]['sub'];

$mySub = 0;
$comp_term = 0;

foreach ($widgets as $widget){

   $agregated_term = 0;
   $sub = $widget['sub'];
   $mySub = $mySub + $sub;
   $term = $widget['term'];
   $myQty = $widget['qty'];

    echo "##########################################################################\n";
    echo "Sub = " . $widget['sub'] . " | My Sub = $mySub | Term = $term  |  Previous Term = $comp_term\n";
    echo "##########################################################################\n";

   $agregated_term = 0;

   for ($x = 0; $x < $term; $x++) {
        $agregated_term++;


        if($myQty < $mySub && $myQty > 0){
            $myQty = $mySub;
        }

        if ($agregated_term < $comp_term){
             if($myQty === 0){
                 break;
             }

             $myQty = $myQty - $sub;
             echo "$agregated_term | $myQty\n";
         }else{
             if($myQty === 0){
                 break;
             }

             $myQty = $myQty - $mySub;
             echo "$agregated_term | $myQty -- agregated\n";
         }

    }

    $comp_term = $agregated_term;

}

?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is really loop-related, but you could use `for ($x = 0; $x < $widget['term']; $x++) {` and eliminate your `$term` variable.  Also, there is a significant speed advantage in your echo statements if you were to use [Commas instead of Periods](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/)

Comment: Also, you can use `$myQty -= $mySub` instead of `$myQty = $myQty - $mySub;` making more efficient use of [assignment operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Comment: Good call on the assignment operators -- These are exactly the types of improvements I am looking for --  Also I never knew about the advantage of commas over periods.. Thanks for that!